# Is there a built-in way to output an instance of data class as a compilable string?

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have an instance of the following class:

```
data class User(val name: String, val startedOn: LocalDate, val score: BigDecimal)
```

Its toString() method is provided automatically and it outputs this:

```
val user = User("Mike", LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 2), BigDecimal.TEN)
        println(user)
User(name=Mike, startedOn=2021-01-02, score=10)
```

Is there another standard function to provide a compilable String for an instance of any data class:

```
User("Mike", LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 2), BigDecimal("10"))
```

Of course, I can write something myself, using reflection, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. This will allow me to write unit tests faster.

Edit: I'm trying to quickly replace real API calls with mocks. So Id like to add something my code calling the API:

```
val request = getRequest(...)
println(toCompilableString(request))
val response = myApi.call(request)
println(toCompilableString(response))
```

and use that output in my tests like this:

```
    val request = <output from the first println>
    val response = <output from the second println>
every { myApi.call(request) } returns response
```

TIA!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What do you do with the generated code? Depending on what you do with it, it might be easier and more robust to write a compiler plugin or use codegen libraries.

Comment: @Joffrey can you suggest a codegen library to accomplish that?

Comment: I did in my answer: Kotlin Poet, but it won't be as magical as you think though. I don't know of others at the moment, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to my knowledge to do this, but there are libraries that can help, such as [Kotlin Poet](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/). However, you won't get the automatic behaviour you're looking for.

If you really want to do this with pure Kotlin, the only "built-in" way I can think of right now is to override `toString()`. You don't have to use reflection, but you'll have to construct the String you want by hand. For instance, something like:

```
data class User(val name: String, val startedOn: LocalDate, val score: BigDecimal) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return """User("$name", ${startedOn.toCompilableString()}, BigDecimal("$score"))"""
    }

    private fun LocalDate.toCompilableString() =
        "LocalDate.of($dayOfMonth, $monthValue, $year)"

}
```

Comment: I did not want to override toString, sorry for a vague question. I've edited my question to remove that ambiguity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also miss this functionality, especially when writing unit tests, you know the code works, and you want to check the data class with what was generated to prevent regression. Just checking it against to toString() of the dataclass is ugly and not a fully test suite